# React Native RSS Feed reader issue

Tags: rss, react-native

I am using React Native and trying to read and then parse an RSS Feed.  I am following this tutorial:

https://getsiphon.com/docs/build-a-youtube-browser/

I am using a bit of the code, but trying to use a different RSS Feed.  For example:

https://fivejs.codeschool.com/feed.rss

Here is the specific code I am having trouble with:

```
getNews() {
  var url = "https://fivejs.codeschool.com/feed.rss"
  fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, "text/xml");
    var items = doc.getElementsByTagName('item');
    var objs = []
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      objs.push({
        title: items[i].childNodes[0]
      })
    }
    console.log("yay! made it here")
    console.log("objs length: ", objs.length)
    console.log("objs: ", objs[0])
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', error);
  });
}
```

Everything is fine up to the point where I am console logging out the objs array.  In other words I see the yay! made it here message and I also see the objs.length message (25).  Once it gets to the next part I do not see the first item in the array.

As a note, I am building my code and running it in a iOS simulator using Xcode.  I am not sure if the debug output console has anything to do with it, but I can't imagine it would since it does output the other messages.  I even tried to console.log the items[i].childNodes[0] in the for loop and didn't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this would help you but following the same tutorial for my own project i had to check two main points to make everything work:

- Check the labels on your XML, sometimes this will mess up your parsing.
- Inside the loop you can select another property. For example, in my case trying to parse a blog rss, i got "Item" (like 12 items) and inside that i get "Title" so i did this:

  ```
  var item = doc.getElementsByTagName('item');

  for(i=0; i < item.length; i++){

  var title = item[i].getElementsByTagName('title');
  console.log(title[0].textContent);

  }
  ```

With this you can create an element (maybe a dictionary?) and then push it inside your array.
I hope this helps you in some way.